# How to initialize a template functions with multiple parameter concisely?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template function with many template parameters, it looks like this:

```
template <int a, int b, int c>
void foo(){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < a ; i ++)
       for(int j = 0 ; j < b ; j ++)
           for(int k = 0 ; k < c ; k ++)
               //do something
}
```

In this case, template parameters (a b c) are used so that compiler could unroll these loops. But in practice, these parameters could take a lot of values. Say, if each of a/b/c could take a value from [1,2,3,4], then you get a total of 64 template functions to initialize. So, your code would be like:

```
if(a == 1 && b == 1 && c == 1) foo<1,1,1>();
else if(a == 1 && b == 1 &&c == 2) foo<1,1,2>();
//......
else foo<4,4,4>();
```

That's a lot of hideous coding. So, do you have any concise way to do that?

Comment: Using function templates for such use cases is probably not a good idea. Use a regular function with three arguments `void foo(int a, int b, int c) { ... }`

Comment: The compiler can even unroll these loops if the limits are not known.  In GCC the documentation of [`-funroll-loops`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.1.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) states »Unroll loops whose number of iterations can be determined at compile time or upon entry to the loop« which is the case here, so the optimizer should consider unrolling.  But don't use `-funroll-loops` explicitly.  It will unroll *all* loops and make your code horribly slow due to cache misses.

Comment: @RSahu I have to use templates, cause unroll optimization is critical to performance, and foo is a GPU kernel.

Comment: @HenriMenke In my program, the compiler does not seem to unroll automatically.

Comment: @ticy Is it a CUDA kernel?  Use [`#pragma unroll`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#pragma-unroll) on your loop.

Comment: Yes, but when a/b/c are function parameters, instead of template parameters, it seems that compiler can not unroll the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can eliminate a lot of the duplication by using nested template functions to determine each template argument, one at a time.  This is kind of a hack, and if the range is fairly substantial then you may want to use code generation to create these wrappers.  It's not super-ideal, but writing three functions with four cases each certainly beats writing 4<sup>3</sup> conditionals.

```
void foo0(int a, int b, int c)
{
    switch (a) {
        case 1: foo1<1>(b, c); break;
        case 2: foo1<2>(b, c); break;
        case 3: foo1<3>(b, c); break;
        case 4: foo1<4>(b, c); break;
    }
}

template <int a>
void foo1(int b, int c)
{
    switch (b) {
        case 1: foo2<a, 1>(c); break;
        case 2: foo2<a, 2>(c); break;
        case 3: foo2<a, 3>(c); break;
        case 4: foo2<a, 4>(c); break;
    }
}

template <int a, int b>
void foo2(int c)
{
    switch (c) {
        case 1: foo<a, b, 1>(); break;
        case 2: foo<a, b, 2>(); break;
        case 3: foo<a, b, 3>(); break;
        case 4: foo<a, b, 4>(); break;
    }
}
```

You can delegate this entire task to the compiler, but the code is significantly longer than this one snippet, so you should only go down that trail if your range is larger than [1, 5).  Here is [an example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5120feb76fd8cafa) of this approach.  It's verbose and kludgy (and could probably be simplified by someone smarter) but it will generate the decision tree entirely at compile-time.  Note that the tree is not optimal, but that may or may not matter in your case.

```
#include <iostream>

template <int a, int b, int c>
void foo()
{
    std::cout << "foo<" << a << "," << b << "," << c << ">()\n";
}

// Class wrapper so that we can generically apply this function.
template <int a, int b, int c>
struct foo_wrapper
{
    void operator()() { foo<a, b, c>(); }
};

template <template <int, int, int> class fn, int min, int max, int a, int b, int i>
struct caller_p3
{
    static void call(int c) {
        if (c == i) {
            fn<a, b, i>()();
        } else {
            caller_p3<fn, min, max, a, b, i + 1>::call(c);
        }
    }
};

template <template <int, int, int> class fn, int min, int max, int a, int b>
struct caller_p3<fn, min, max, a, b, max>
{
    static void call(int c) {
        if (c == max) {
            fn<a, b, max>()();
        } else {
            // out of range, throw?
        }
    }
};

template <template <int, int, int> class fn, int min, int max, int a, int i>
struct caller_p2
{
    static void call(int b, int c) {
        if (b == i) {
            caller_p3<fn, min, max, a, i, min>::call(c);
        } else {
            caller_p2<fn, min, max, a, i + 1>::call(b, c);
        }
    }
};

template <template <int, int, int> class fn, int min, int max, int a>
struct caller_p2<fn, min, max, a, max>
{
    static void call(int b, int c) {
        if (b == max) {
            caller_p3<fn, min, max, a, max, min>::call(c);
        } else {
            // out of range, throw?
        }
    }
};

template <template <int, int, int> class fn, int min, int max, int i>
struct caller_p1
{
    static void call(int a, int b, int c) {
        if (a == i) {
            caller_p2<fn, min, max, i, min>::call(b, c);
        } else {
            caller_p1<fn, min, max, i + 1>::call(a, b, c);
        }
    }
};

template <template <int, int, int> class fn, int min, int max>
struct caller_p1<fn, min, max, max>
{
    static void call(int a, int b, int c) {
        if (a == max) {
            caller_p2<fn, min, max, max, min>::call(b, c);
        } else {
            // out of range, throw?
        }
    }
};

// Generic caller.
template <template <int, int, int> class fn, int min, int max>
struct caller
{
    void operator()(int a, int b, int c) {
        caller_p1<fn, min, max, min>::call(a, b, c);
    }
};

int main() {
    caller<foo_wrapper, 0, 5>()(1, 2, 3);
    caller<foo_wrapper, 0, 5>()(0, 0, 5);
    caller<foo_wrapper, 0, 5>()(5, 1, 0);
}
```

[Here is a C++11 implementation](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6cc31983f0842d64) that uses variadic templates to allow any number of template arguments to `foo()`:

```
#include <iostream>

template <int a, int b, int c>
void foo()
{
    std::cout << "foo<" << a << "," << b << "," << c << ">()\n";
}

// Class wrapper so that we can generically apply this function.
template <int a, int b, int c>
struct foo_wrapper
{
    void operator()() { foo<a, b, c>(); }
};

// Caller implementation.
template <typename T, template <T...> class fn, T min, T max, T i, T... parms>
struct caller_impl
{
    template <typename... Tail>
    static void call(T head, Tail... tail)
    {
        if (head == i) {
            caller_impl<T, fn, min, max, min, parms..., i>::call(tail...);
        } else {
            caller_impl<T, fn, min, max, i + 1, parms...>::call(head, tail...);
        }
    }

    static void call()
    {
        fn<parms...>()();
    }
};

// Specialization for i==max
template <typename T, template <T...> class fn, T min, T max, T... parms>
struct caller_impl<T, fn, min, max, max, parms...>
{
    template <typename... Tail>
    static void call(T head, Tail... tail)
    {
        if (head == max) {
            caller_impl<T, fn, min, max, min, parms..., max>::call(tail...);
        } else {
            // Out of range, throw?
        }
    }

    static void call()
    {
        fn<parms...>()();
    }
};

// Helper to kick off the call.
template <typename T, template <T...> class fn, T min, T max, typename... parms>
void caller(parms... p)
{
    caller_impl<T, fn, min, max, min>::call(p...);
}

int main() {
    caller<int, foo_wrapper, 0, 5>(1, 2, 3);
    caller<int, foo_wrapper, 0, 5>(0, 0, 5);
    caller<int, foo_wrapper, 0, 5>(5, 1, 0);
}
```

Comment: May I suggest `if constexpr( )` to help with the verbosity? Not C++11, though.

Answer (score 1):

You may create an array of functions:

```
template <int a, int b, int c> void foo() { 
    // Your implementation
}

// Helper function which does the dispatch
template <std::size_t ... Is>
void foo(int index, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    using f_type = void();
    f_type* f[] = {&foo<1 + Is / 16, 1 + (Is / 4) % 4, 1 + Is % 4>...};

    f[index]();
}

// function which call f<a, b, c>()
// a, b, c should be in [1;4]
void foo(int a, int b, int c)
{
    foo((a - 1) * 16 + (b - 1) * 4 + c - 1, std::make_index_sequence<64>());   
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/Prb84p)

Answer (score 1):

> That's a lot of hideous coding. So, do you have any concise way to do that?

With an extra layer of indirection that *constructs* the right call iteratively, you can easily solve it:

```
#include<iostream>

template<int I, int J, int K>
void foo() {
    std::cout << I << "/" << J << "/" << K << std::endl;
}

template<int... I, typename... O>
void foo(int v, O... o) {
    switch(v) {
    case 1: return foo<I..., 1>(o...);
    case 2: return foo<I..., 2>(o...);
    case 3: return foo<I..., 3>(o...);
    case 4: return foo<I..., 4>(o...);
    }
}

int main() {
    foo(1, 2, 1);
}
```

See it up and running on [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mEMdherVgsc8EpFp).

The basic idea is that you pop up a value at the time and put it in the template parameters list for later uses. If your `N` is greater than 4, you can just add more lines to the `switch` statement and that's all.

It requires at least C++11, but I don't think that's a problem nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

First, I have to ask why you need to explicitly instantiate your function for certain cases - often the compiler can figure this out for itself.  For example, this just works:

```
template<int a, int b, int c>
void foo()
{
...
}

int main(const int argc, const char* argv[]) {
  foo<2,4,1>();
  ...
}
```

Perhaps you need to use `foo()` in compilation units other than the one where it is defined.  In that case, you do need explicit instantiation for every case you plan to use.  For the [a,b,c] in (1,2,3,4) case, this does the trick:

```
#define _FWD_DECLc(a,b,c) foo<a, b, c>();
#define _FWD_DECLb(a,b)   _FWD_DECLc(a,b,1)  _FWD_DECLc(a,b,2) _FWD_DECLc(a,b,3) _FWD_DECLc(a,b,4)
#define _FWD_DECLa(a)     _FWD_DECLb(a,1)    _FWD_DECLb(a,2)   _FWD_DECLb(a,3)   _FWD_DECLb(a,4)
#define _FWD_DECL         _FWD_DECLa(1)      _FWD_DECLa(2)     _FWD_DECLa(3)     _FWD_DECLa(4)

void blah() {
  _FWD_DECL
}
```

The idea is that `blah()` is never going to be called but in order to compile it, the compiler has to instantiate `foo()` for all combinations of ([1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4]).  Granted, this will get unwieldy again for more than three template parameters and if [a,b,c] can go much higher than 4, but for this case it's pretty succinct.